# PHP, trying to add captcha to existing form

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I am not a PHP programmer, but have used it a touch, enough to put in a contact form.  However, I am trying to add a captcha field, which now works but the form does not validate it - so it submits no matter what

Can anybody help please? sorry if the code is messy and thanks in advance

code at the top of my page

```
        <?php session_start() ?> 
<?php  
      //If the form is submitted  
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty  
     if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $name = trim($_POST['name']);  
     }  

       //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty  
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted  
     if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) 
     {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $email = trim($_POST['email']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure comments were entered  
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {  
         $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));  
     } else {  
         $message = trim($_POST['message']);  
     } 

     /*captcha 2*/ 

    if(isset($_POST["captcha"])) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
    if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"]) {
    }
    }
    //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...

    //If there is no error, send the email  
     if(!isset($hasError)) {  
         $emailTo = 'email address'; //Put your own email address here  
         $emailTo = 'email address'; //Put your own email address here  
         $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n $message";  
         $headers = 'From: website form <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' .         
         $email;  

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);  
         $emailSent = true;  
     }
     }
?> 

   Code in the form:

    [php]<?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>  

        <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information.           Thank    you.</p>  
  <?php } ?>  

  <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>  
      <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>  
      <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong> for contacting us. Your email was successfully sent and we will be in touch with you soon.</p>  
      <?php } ?>  

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">  
     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="name">Name</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="required">
         </p> 
     </div>  

     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="email">Email</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="required">
         </p> 
     </div>  

     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="subject" value="" id="subject" class="required">
         </p> 

     </div>  

     <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  

         <p>
         <label for="message">Message</label><br />
         <textarea rows="5" name="message" value="" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
         </p> 

     </div>  
     <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  


         <img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha image">
         <p>
         <label for="captcha">(antispam code, 3 black symbols)</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="captcha" maxlength="3" id="captcha" class="required">
         </p> 

     </div>  
     <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />  
 </form>
 [/php]
```

Comment: Does your file have a call to session_start()?  Without it, $_SESSION['catpcha'] will be empty (and potentially throw a notice).  Also, note that you should be checking that the stored captcha value isn't blank.  Otherwise, the user could simply by pass the captcha by not loading the image.  if(!empty($_SESSION['captcha']) && $_SESSION['captcha'] === $captchaFromUser) { valid }

Comment: Checking if the session-stored captcha value is empty?  It's the code I posted above.  The $captchaFromUser would be the $_POST['captcha'] by the way.  It's typically better to avoid directly accessing $_POST values without checking that they're set first.  If they're not set, then you'll get a notice.

Comment: sorry I had not seen the code before, so I have replaced if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
 with if(!empty($_SESSION['captcha']) && $_SESSION['captcha'] === $captchaFromUser)

Comment: so now, it seems to still submit even if not captcha entered, but then it clears all form fields and no error message - as if starting again...sorry, and thanks for the help, been trying to figure this out for 3 nights, figured I need an expert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[edit ] 2011-12-20 8:22pm CST - updated the second block of code with the final code that the OP is using - based on off site chat.***

There's a better way to write the code.  I'm putting an example of this below.  Ask questions and I'll update the code with comments explaining.  I revamped the if statement you had for the captcha so that it didn't need a double `if`.  Using `||` (or) in the `if` statement causes PHP to stop after testing the first condition (if the first condition evaluates to true).  Therefore, if the variable is not set it never moves on to the comparison of POST with SESSION.

Also, I defaulted your hasError variable to false, and am testing for the boolean value.  This is better *because it makes sense*.  Think about the programmers who will come after you.  If it makes sense, it'll be easier to work with.  *You might be that programmer* :)

[edited to add `session_start();`]

```
<?php
session_start();

// default value
$hasError = false;

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if( trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        }  
    }

    if( ! isset( $_POST["captcha"] ) || $_SESSION["captcha"] != $_POST["captcha"] ) {
        $hasError = true;
        echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission<br>';
        echo $_POST['captcha' . ' != ' . $_SESSION['captcha'] . '<br>';
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email  
    if( $hasError == false ) {  
        $emailTo = 'email@email.com'; //Put your own email address here  
        $emailTo = 'email@email.com'; //Put your own email address here  
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n $message";  

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! REMOVE \r\n from $emailTo or your form will be hacked !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        $headers = 'From: website form <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;  

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);  
        $emailSent = true;  
    } else {

    }
}
```

[edit - full code, edited and (hopefully) improved]

```
    <?php
session_start();

function clean_for_email( $inbound )
{
   return str_replace( array( "\n", "\r" ), "", $inbound );
}
// I really like the name of this function. :D
function outputInput( $name, $required )
{
    $attribs[] = "name=\"{$name}\"";
    $attribs[] = "id=\"{$name}\"";
    $attribs[] = $required?'class="required"':'';
    $attribs[] = 'type="text"';


    if ( count( $_POST ) && array_key_exists( $name, $_POST ) )
    {
        $attribs[] = 'value="' . htmlspecialchars( $_POST[$name] ) . '"';
    }

    echo '<input ' . implode( ' ', $attribs ) . '>';
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
function outputTextarea( $name, $required, $rows = 5 )
{
    $attribs[] = "name=\"{$name}\"";
    $attribs[] = "id=\"{$name}\"";
    $attribs[] = $required?'class="required"':'';
    $attribs[] = 'rows="5"';
    $value = '';

    if ( count( $_POST ) && array_key_exists( $name, $_POST ) )
    {
        $value = htmlspecialchars( $_POST[$name] );
    }

    echo '<textarea ' . implode( ' ', $attribs ) . '>' . $value . '</textarea>';
}

// default value
$hasError = false;
$emailSent = false;

//If the form is submitted
if( count( $_POST ) && isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if ( ! preg_match( '/^.+@.+$/i', trim( $_POST['email'] ) ) ) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if( trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        }  
    }

    if ( ! array_key_exists( 'captcha', $_POST ) || $_SESSION['captcha'] != $_POST["captcha"] ) {
        $hasError = true;
    }

    if( ! $hasError )
    {
        $captchaValid = true;
        //If there is no error, send the email
        if( $hasError == false ) {
            $emailTo = 'xxx'; //Put your own email address here
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n $message";
            $headers = 'From: website form <'.clean_for_email( $emailTo ).'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . clean_for_email( $email );
            mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
            $emailSent = true;
        } else {

        }
    }
}
?>

<? if( $hasError ) : ?>
    <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information Thank you.</p>  
<? endif; ?>

<? if( $emailSent == true) : ?>
    <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>  
    <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong> for contacting us. Your email was successfully sent and we will be in touch with you soon.</p>  
<? endif; ?>  

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">  
    <div>  
        <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br />
        <? outputInput( 'name', true ); ?>
        </p> 
    </div>  

    <div>  
        <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br />
        <? outputInput( 'email', true ); ?>
        </p> 
    </div>  

    <div>  
        <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
        <? outputInput( 'subject', true ); ?>
        </p> 
    </div>  

    <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  
        <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br />
        <? outputTextarea( 'message', true ); ?>
        </p> 
    </div>  
    <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  
        <img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha image">
        <p>
        <label for="captcha">(antispam code, 3 black symbols)</label><br />
        <? outputInput( 'captcha', true ); ?>
        </p> 
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />  
</form>
```

Comment: the form fields are being cleared because there's nothing in the form code to re-output the values just submitted.

Comment: :)  it's your script.  do what makes you happy.  _play with it_ you'll learn if you do something wrong. (the answer is yes, you can remove it too)

Comment: I commented out the actual call to mail because I didn't want to actually send mail while testing.

Answer (score 0):

<s>if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))</s>

You're missing a bracket.

Edited to show entire code.... Brackets added for captcha conditionals which were missing. As is, your code did not check if the captcha was set via post. It was only checking the session variable against the post variable. If both were blank, the form would mail. You may still have issues with captcha.php or the session variable.

```
<?php  
      //If the form is submitted  
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty  
     if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $name = trim($_POST['name']);  
     }  

       //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty  
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted  
     if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) 
     {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $email = trim($_POST['email']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure comments were entered  
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {  
         $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));  
     } else {  
         $message = trim($_POST['message']);  
     }  
     }

     /*captcha 2*/ 


    if(isset($_POST["captcha"])) {
    if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])
    {
    //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...

    //If there is no error, send the email  
     if(!isset($hasError)) {  
         $emailTo = 'enquiries@sjbprojects.com'; //Put your own email address here  
         $emailTo = 'sjbullen@gmail.com'; //Put your own email address here  
         $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n $message";  
         $headers = 'From: SJB Projects website form <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' .          $email;  

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);  
         $emailSent = true;  
    }
   else
    {
    echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission';
    }
    }  


    } else {

     ///message here if CAPTCHA is not set (via post)

    }

    }  
     ?> 

  <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>  

        <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information.           Thank    you.</p>  
  <?php } ?>  

  <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>  
      <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>  
      <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong> for contacting SJB Projects. Your email was successfully sent and we will be in touch with you soon.</p>  
      <?php } ?>  

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">  
     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="name">Name</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="required">
         </p> 
     </div>  

     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="email">Email</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="required">
         </p> 
     </div>  

     <div>  

         <p>
         <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="subject" value="" id="subject" class="required">
         </p> 

     </div>  

     <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  

         <p>
         <label for="message">Message</label><br />
         <textarea rows="5" name="message" value="" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
         </p> 

     </div>  
     <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">  


         <img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha image">
         <p>
         <label for="captcha">(antispam code, 3 black symbols)</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="captcha" maxlength="3" id="captcha" class="required">
         </p> 

     </div>  
     <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />  
 </form>
```

Comment: thanks - where do I need to add the bracket? a third one at the end?

Comment: It should be -- if(isset($_POST["captcha"])) {   -- (open bracket after the line I posted). And simply add another closing bracket at the bottom with the other closing brackets.

Comment: I have edited the code above, it seems to register if the captcha is correct, but shows no error and clears the fields if it is left empty....

Comment: I added the code to my answer... showing where to place a message if no $_POST['captcha'] exists. THat was missing from your code as well.

Comment: thanks for taking the time on this.  I have a general validation message above my form code (which works for existing fields), so I guess I need to include it so that if captcha is not set to also show that message (as it does for the other fields)

Comment: that braceless `if` is perfectly valid, albeit very confusing code.  This `if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"]){
{` however is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the message, I have edited my code.  So the captcha works if filled in, but still does not validate correctly.  I am trying to do it so that the validation message in the form, also shows if the captcha is incorrect or invalid - thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you certain the session variable is being set correctly? You might want to simply echo $_SESSION['captcha']; to see if it's there.

Comment: i'm not really certain of anything! kind of need hand holding here

Comment: At the top of the PHP add this ---> echo $_SESSION['captcha'].'-captcha.';  <----- then submit the form... is anything there other than the word "-captcha"? The problem may be in the captcha.php file.